# Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, floating-action-button, android-api-levels

When I'm trying to build the application it will show the `android.view.InflateException` in FloatingActionButton? I really don't know what causes the error.

**Login.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_image" >
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lLayout_logincontainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="40dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:src="@drawable/project"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/aTxt_UserName"
                style="@style/edittextstyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="User Name"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                >

            </EditText>


        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <!--  Password Label -->
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/eTxt_PassWord"
                style="@style/edittextstyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_login"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:text="Login"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorTrade_2"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:rippleColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_user_add" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">
       </style>
    <style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/white</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
        <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    <style name="edittextstyle">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
        <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:inputType">textFilter</item>
    </style>
    <style name="userProfileText">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
        <item name="android:padding">5dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.trade.seems">
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" android:required="true" />
<application android:allowBackup="true"
    android:name=".utils.MyApplication"
             android:isolatedProcess="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_api_key" />
    <activity android:name=".uil.SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait">
         <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ual.login.LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"/>
</application>
</manifest>
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.trade.seems"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/ch.acra/acra/pom.xml'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/ch.acra/acra/pom.properties'

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.5.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    /*Support Libraries */
    compile project(':autocomplete_library')
    compile project(':ViewPagerIndicator-Library')
    /*Third party Libraries */
    compile 'es.guiguegon:gallerymodule:1.3.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.+'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.0.1'
    //Library to handle Material design for all Version of android
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
    //Library Glide is to handle Images Instead of picasso
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'


    /*Google  Android Support Library*/
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1' 
}
```

**Complete Error Trace**

```
com.trade.seems E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.trade.seemys, PID: 8225 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activityComponentInfo{com.tradezap.seemysteps/com.trade.seems.ual.login.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #84: Binary XML file line #84: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                            Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #84: Binary XML file line #84: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                               at com.trade.seems.ual.login.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:55)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                            Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #84: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                               at com.trade.seems.ual.login.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:55) 
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                               at com.trade.seems.ual.login.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:55) 
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Landroid/widget/ImageView;Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatDrawableManager;)V in class Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageHelper; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper' appears in /data/app/com.tradezap.seemysteps-1/base.apk)
                                                                               at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:133)
                                                                               at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:110)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                               at com.trade.seems.ual.login.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:55) 
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: @TimCastelijns can you guide which one i missed,please

Comment: Add xml code in which your fab button is present.

Comment: Can u post that layout file where u r using FloatingActionButton

Comment: @VishalPuri thank you,please wait i will do it now.

Comment: @Raghavendra i added pls check it now.

Comment: In your `xml` code where is the `FloatingActionButton`.

Comment: @MohanRajS I couldn't find the FloatingActionButton???

Comment: sorry all my edited revision is pending. thank you for the resoponse

Comment: @Raghavendra now it showing, please check it.

Comment: Make sure that your `LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity` in java code .

Comment: @Ironman Yes, May I share the class?

Comment: @MohanRajS can you tell me what is your `gradle` plugin version ?

Comment: @Ironman "gradle-2.14.1-all" this is my grade plugin version

Comment: @MohanRajS remove this `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1' ` you don't require it. and then try to `clean` and `rebuild` project.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your Case, Problem is in your styles.xml, your base theme name is AppBaseTheme. Change it to AppTheme as you can see you have used AppTheme in your Mainfest file.

I have listed all the reasons that may cause  class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton. Please read the points carefully.

1. FAB button is Design Library Cpmponent. Your Activity must extend **AppCompatActivity** instead of **Activity**.
2. Your activity theme also should be appropriate **Theme.AppCompat** theme. Also FAB requires colorAccent. Make sure you have them inside your styles.xml.

   ```
   <!-- Base application theme. -->
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.AppTheme">
   <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
   </style>

   <style name="Base.AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
   <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
   <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
   <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
   </style>
   ```
3. Use **app:backgroundTint="@color/your_color"** instead of android:backgroundTint.
4. Don't miss out on adding design library inside your project build.gradle file

   ```
   dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    ...
   }
   ```
5. Update Support Library on SDK Manager in Extras > Android Support Repository and Android Support Library

Hope it solves your error.

Comment: My entire project having this issue, FAB inflate error, Just now i commented FAB on  Login screen Design, Now error showing in another screen. Did u face exception like this?

Comment: No Vishal i just roll out my old code and doing again now. its a big headache now.

Comment: Can you please add Style and manifest(LoginActivity block) file to your question?

Comment: I added the Styles and Mainfest files, please check it, And thanks for consideration.

Comment: Im sorry for previous reply i tested your code. Problem is in your styles.xml, your base theme name is AppBaseTheme. Change it to AppTheme as you can see you have used AppTheme in your Mainfest file.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i have resolve the problem by your answer and thanks again four guidance

Comment: can you please look up my question and suggest answer please. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39991118/multipart-entity-file-uploading-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `backgroundTint` on the API 21+ then 
just use this line in FloatingActionButton (`app` instead of `android`):

```
app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
```

Here is the sample layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        android:tint="#FFF"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```