# Multipart entity file uploading java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, asyncfileupload, multifile-uploader

Multipart entity file uploading with array of files.
I have mentioned the error code below, please help me resolve this issue. Exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2.
Thanks in Advance.

Code:

```
try{
        int i = 0;
        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        int selectedImgLength = selectedItems.size();
        File[] mfile = new File[selectedImgLength];
        for( i = 0; i<selectedImgLength;i++){
            //mfile[i]= selectedItems.get(i);// Error InCompatiable type
            mfile[i] = new File(selectedItems.get(i));
        }
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        entityBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        entityBuilder.addPart( "userfile[" + i + "]", new FileBody(mfile[i]));
        HttpEntity entity = entityBuilder.build();
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);

        httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
        System.out.println("POST IMAGE Response"+response);
    }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: May i know why my question getting down vote. please give me the comment, it will help to improve ask question in stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you do

```
entityBuilder.addPart( "userfile[" + i + "]", new FileBody(mfile[i]));
```

you have already exited the for loop and `i` has become equals in size to `selectedImgLength`, therefore you will get a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

try changing so that adding the file to the `entityBuilder` within the for loop.

Comment: Thanks bro, sorry I done a big mistake. Thank you for your guidance. Now i Fixed it.