# Firebase UI and FloatingActionButton incompatibility

Tags: android, firebase, floating-action-button, firebaseui

Good evening!

**Edited**

**Here's my situation:**

I'm using FirebaseUI to store in FirebaseStorage and FirebaseDatabase, and retrieve from Database only. I'm trying to use a FloatingActionButton in activity_main.xml (actually is the FloatingActionButton included in the Basic Activity you choose once you start a project) to take a picture. But when I compile the next dependencies

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.0.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:1.0.1'
```

it's not possible to run the application. It appears this exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: mx.com.jamba.pruebas, PID: 22567
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mx.com.jamba.pruebas/mx.com.jamba.pruebas.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143)
                  at mx.com.jamba.pruebas.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:71)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6259)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143) 
                  at mx.com.jamba.pruebas.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:71) 
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6259) 
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143) 
                  at mx.com.jamba.pruebas.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:71) 
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6259) 
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618) 
               Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Landroid/widget/ImageView;Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatDrawableManager;)V in class Landroid/support/v7/widget/AppCompatImageHelper; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper' appears in /data/data/mx.com.jamba.pruebas/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-appcompat-v7-25.0.1_3703da7076adad9ae91e29d9a19b5ed5b7cb0669-classes.dex)
                  at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:133)
                  at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:110)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143) 
                  at mx.com.jamba.pruebas.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:71) 
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6259) 
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

The only line of code that the exception points in my code is the #71, and it has the following piece of code:

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

This is my Style.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Also, this is my FloatingActionButton in activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_dialer"
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton" />
```

The problem is that when I try to *Run 'app'* in my Moto G4 Android 6.0.1, the application crashes. I dedicated a little time to compile the project dependency by dependency and I realized that when I erase the FirebaseUI dependencies the application was executed, but without FurebaseUI functions. The way that I found to execute the application was erase the FloatingActionButton and use a normal Button instead, but I need a FloatingActionButton.

If you guys need more info or code, comment and I'll gladly put it in the post!

Comment: So what's the error message? What's your layout that doesn't work? What theme are you using? How are you using FirebaseUI?

Comment: Hello! @ianhanniballake I edited the post, I hope the post is clearer now.

Comment: Add more of the exception. Look for lines with "Caused by"

Comment: @cricket_007 done! exception edited :)

Comment: Looks like it can't find the constructor for the FloatingActionButton... `NoSuchMethodError`. `FloatingActionButton.<init>`

Comment: @cricket_007 yes! The rare situation is when I erase FirebaseUI dependencies, the application is executed, it doesn't retrieve anything from Firebase but at least it's executed.

Comment: You could try creating a github issue. https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues I'm not really sure if this is something that can be answered if it really is a dependency conflict

Comment: What version of the Android support design library are you including?

Comment: @hatboysam com.android.support:design:23.4.0

Comment: @hatboysam I am also facing the same issue. I tried with older version of Firebase UI Library also.But I got the same error.I am also having the FloatingActionButton in my activity layout.When I remove the firebase ui dependency everything starts working

Comment: Your problem seems like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39917266/6103651