# Inflate Exception Inside Fragment Class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, inflate-exception, binary-xml

I am working on a project that requires fragments. Whenever I test run the project, in my fragment class, I get an exception pointing to the inflaterline of my oncreateview method, like shown below.

```
Process: com.example.joey.maranathahealthblog, PID: 29380
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class <unknown>
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
    at com.example.joey.maranathahealthblog.BlogTabs.TabsFragments.HygieneClone.onCreateView(HygieneClone.java:27)
```

This is the snippet of my fragment class

```
public class HygieneClone extends Fragment {


    public HygieneClone() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        //  error occurs here
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_hygiene_clone, container, false); 
    }

}
```

My layout file is shown below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.joey.maranathahealthblog.BlogTabs.TabsFragments.HygieneClone">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/hygiene_recyclerView"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/newPost_Fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"/>
```

What could be causing this, as the app does not even load the first screen due to this exception.

Comment: show `fragment_hygiene_clone` xml

Comment: Do you have  compile "com.android.support:design:X.X.X" in ur gradlew ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK, that's the layout file shown above.

Comment: I will remove every single control from xml file to see if program runs well without it. if good, then problem goes directly to this control. if remains the same after removing all controls, then the code must contains  error, not the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Cause you don't have dependencies relate to android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.
Try add --
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0' 
in your build.gradle

Comment: I have added the dependency but the problem still persists.

Comment: 1.press Ctrl and click the android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton in your xml file,can you jump to the FloatingActionButton.java file ?
2.Try Clean Project?

Comment: I've tried cleaning the project and running the app again. The same error shows.

Comment: did you got a NoSuchMethodError too?See this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39916850/error-inflating-class-android-support-design-widget-floatingactionbutton-in-andr