# Android Studio App Force Closing: setContentView(R.layout.acitvity_main) error

Tags: java, android

### My MainAcivity.java

```
package com.example.sinon.razercomponentsreservation;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.sinon.razercomponentsreservation.database.DatabaseManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseManager db;
    EditText snumber;
    Button find;
    TextView info;
    FloatingActionButton fab, fab2, fab3, fab4;
    Animation fab_open,fab_close,rotate_forward,rotate_backward;
    Boolean isFabOpen = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        db = new DatabaseManager(this);

        fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab2 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab1);
        fab3 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab2);
        fab4 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab3);

        fab_open = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fab_open);
        fab_close = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fab_close);
        rotate_forward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.rotate_forward);
        rotate_backward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.rotate_backward);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                fab2.show();
                fab3.show();
                fab4.show();
                animateFAB();
            }
        });

        fab2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent launchIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,CustomerReservation.class);
                startActivity(launchIntent);
                if(isFabOpen){

                    fab.startAnimation(rotate_backward);
                    fab2.startAnimation(fab_close);
                    fab3.startAnimation(fab_close);
                    fab4.startAnimation(fab_close);
                    fab2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    fab3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    fab4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    fab2.setClickable(false);
                    fab3.setClickable(false);
                    fab4.setClickable(false);
                    isFabOpen = false;
                    Log.d("Fab", "close");

                } else {

                    fab.startAnimation(rotate_forward);
                    fab2.startAnimation(fab_open);
                    fab3.startAnimation(fab_open);
                    fab4.startAnimation(fab_open);
                    fab2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    fab3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    fab4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    fab2.setClickable(true);
                    fab3.setClickable(true);
                    fab4.setClickable(true);
                    isFabOpen = true;
                    Log.d("Fab","open");

                }
            }
        });

        fab3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent launchIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,EditCustomerInformation.class);
                startActivity(launchIntent);
                if(isFabOpen){

                    fab.startAnimation(rotate_backward);
                    fab2.startAnimation(fab_close);
                    fab3.startAnimation(fab_close);
                    fab4.startAnimation(fab_close);
                    fab2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    fab3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    fab4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    fab2.setClickable(false);
                    fab3.setClickable(false);
                    fab4.setClickable(false);
                    isFabOpen = false;
                    Log.d("Fab", "close");

                } else {

                    fab.startAnimation(rotate_forward);
                    fab2.startAnimation(fab_open);
                    fab3.startAnimation(fab_open);
                    fab4.startAnimation(fab_open);
                    fab2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    fab3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    fab4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    fab2.setClickable(true);
                    fab3.setClickable(true);
                    fab4.setClickable(true);
                    isFabOpen = true;
                    Log.d("Fab","open");

                }
            }
        });

        fab4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent launchIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ReservationList.class);
                startActivity(launchIntent);
                if(isFabOpen){

                    fab.startAnimation(rotate_backward);
                    fab2.startAnimation(fab_close);
                    fab3.startAnimation(fab_close);
                    fab4.startAnimation(fab_close);
                    fab2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    fab3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    fab4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    fab2.setClickable(false);
                    fab3.setClickable(false);
                    fab4.setClickable(false);
                    isFabOpen = false;
                    Log.d("Fab", "close");

                } else {

                    fab.startAnimation(rotate_forward);
                    fab2.startAnimation(fab_open);
                    fab3.startAnimation(fab_open);
                    fab4.startAnimation(fab_open);
                    fab2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    fab3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    fab4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    fab2.setClickable(true);
                    fab3.setClickable(true);
                    fab4.setClickable(true);
                    isFabOpen = true;
                    Log.d("Fab","open");

                }
            }
        });

        find = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchBtn);
        find.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                snumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.customerID);
                info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                String get = snumber.getText().toString();
                String qu = "SELECT * FROM CustomerInfo WHERE customerid = '" + get.toUpperCase() + "'";
                Cursor cursor = db.loadData(qu);

                if(cursor==null||cursor.getCount()==0)
                {
                    assert info != null;
                    info.setText("No Data Available");
                }else
                {
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    String buffer = "";
                    buffer += "Customer ID#: " + cursor.getString(0)+ "\n";
                    buffer += "Name: " + cursor.getString(1)+ "\n";
                    buffer += "Age: " + cursor.getString(2)+ "\n";
                    buffer += "Contact#:" + cursor.getString(3)+ "\n";
                    buffer += "Room Number: " + cursor.getString(4)+ "\n";
                    buffer += "Count of people: " + cursor.getString(5)+ "\n";
                    buffer += "Date of Reservation: " + cursor.getString(6)+ "\n";
                    buffer += "Date pf Accommodation: " + cursor.getString(7)+ "\n";
                    info.setText(buffer);
                }
            }
        });

        info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        info.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                android.app.AlertDialog.Builder alert = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                alert.setTitle("Delete Student");
                alert.setMessage("Are you sure ?");
                alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.customerID);
                        String del = editText.getText().toString();
                        String qu = "DELETE FROM StudentInfo WHERE snumber = '" + del.toUpperCase() + "'";
                        if (db.deleteData(qu)) {
                            Log.d("delete", "done from student");
                        }
                    }
                });
                alert.setNegativeButton("No", null);
                alert.show();
                return true;
            }
        });

    }

    public void animateFAB(){

        if(isFabOpen){

            fab.startAnimation(rotate_backward);
            fab2.startAnimation(fab_close);
            fab3.startAnimation(fab_close);
            fab4.startAnimation(fab_close);
            fab2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            fab3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            fab4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            fab2.setClickable(false);
            fab3.setClickable(false);
            fab4.setClickable(false);
            isFabOpen = false;
            Log.d("Fab", "close");

        } else {

            fab.startAnimation(rotate_forward);
            fab2.startAnimation(fab_open);
            fab3.startAnimation(fab_open);
            fab4.startAnimation(fab_open);
            fab2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            fab3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            fab4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            fab2.setClickable(true);
            fab3.setClickable(true);
            fab4.setClickable(true);
            isFabOpen = true;
            Log.d("Fab","open");

        }
    }
}
```

### My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:an

droid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sinon.razercomponentsreservation">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".CustomerReservation" />
    <activity android:name=".EditCustomerInformation" />
    <activity android:name=".ReservationList"></activity>
</application>
```

My codes don't have errors but my application is force closing when I opened the app and when I checked the logcat I see this stuffs. Please help my with this error I can't find the problem because the logcat don't make any sense at all.

> 10-08 05:27:52.066 1455-1455/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                        Process: com.example.sinon.razercomponentsreservation, PID: 1455
>                                                        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.sinon.razercomponentsreservation/com.example.sinon.razercomponentsreservation.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #70: Error
>   inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
>                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
>                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
>                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #70: Error
>   inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
>                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
>                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
>                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
>                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
>                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
>                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
>                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
>                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>                                                            at com.example.sinon.razercomponentsreservation.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)
>                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
>                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
>                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
>                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
>                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
>                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
>                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
>                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
>                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
>                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
>                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
>                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
>                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
>                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
>                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
>                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
>                                                            at com.example.sinon.razercomponentsreservation.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32) 
>                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
>                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
>                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
>                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
>                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
>                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
>                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
>                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
>                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
>                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                         Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File
>   res/drawable/circle.xml from color state list resource ID #0x7f020055
>                                                            at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:2252)
>                                                            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:343)
>                                                            at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.(FloatingActionButton.java:164)
>                                                            at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.(FloatingActionButton.java:153)
>                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
>                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
>                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
>                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
>                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
>                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
>                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
>                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
>                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
>                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
>                                                            at com.example.sinon.razercomponentsreservation.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32) 
>                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
>                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
>                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
>                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
>                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
>                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
>                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
>                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
>                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
>                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                         Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #2:
>   invalid drawable tag shape
>                                                            at android.content.res.ColorStateList.createFromXmlInner(ColorStateList.java:146)
>                                                            at android.content.res.ColorStateList.createFromXml(ColorStateList.java:129)
>                                                            at android.content.res.Resources.loadColorStateList(Resources.java:2248)
>                                                            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:343) 
>                                                            at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.(FloatingActionButton.java:164) 
>                                                            at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.(FloatingActionButton.java:153) 
>                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
>                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
>                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
>                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
>                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
>   ......
>                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
>                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
>                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
>                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
>                                                            at com.example.sinon.razercomponentsreservation.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32) 
>                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
>                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
>                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
>                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
>                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
>                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
>                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
>                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
>                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
>                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

This blue text from logcat is the only blue text there.

```
//blue text from logcat
MainActivity.java:32
```

That blue text from logcat directs me on this line from my MainActivity.java

```
//line 32
setContentView(R.layout.acitvity_main)
```

Comment: Please provide your "activity_main.xml". Because it is causing problem because of layout.

Comment: share your activity_main.xml

Comment: your using a shape draw able `circle.xml` which has malformed `shape` tag

Comment: Check this [Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39916850/error-inflating-class-android-support-design-widget-floatingactionbutton-in-andr), it may help

Comment: I posted my activity_main.xml on the answers and updated the post because I added the AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: did you correctly declare your FAB ID's with its layout...?

Comment: Yah, I named it fab, fab2,fab3,fab4.